How to add a line of text at the bottom of the table of contents page?
I am using a report document class for my thesis. My advisor has asked me to add a line at the bottom of the table of contents page that displays the word count. How do I do that?

Related: are you wanting the word count to update automatically, or are you willing to type in the word count yourself if you get it through other means?

@Teepeemm I'm planning to write it manually.


My advisor has asked me to add a line at the bottom of the table of contents page

Assuming that you're using the instruction \tableofcontents to create the Table of Contents, I suggest you add the instructions
\par\vfill\noindent Word Count: 999

(or whatever the number is supposed to be...) on the line after the \tableofcontents instruction.
